# using square Picsso android library to load image from custom resource

Tags: java, android, picasso

I was very excited  about Picasso android library . I have an android application that i want to use picasso but i have one problem in a place inside my application

I have a listview (endless) that display images in each item beside some text  , now i don't have the Url for each item in the list ( I am using a stupid api )  , I have to hit the server with specific id ,then the server sent me image url(s) that i can use in Picasso .

example :

```
http://url/id/342
```

and the response look like

```
{
"images":["url_large":"http://........","url_medium":"http://........"]

}
```

I can't pre-load image url . because i have an endless list and for each item i need to call the web service to get it image url .

Can picasso handle this ?

Comment: Picasso is not going to parse the JSON repsonse.  You would have to do that on your own, and then pass Picasso the url that you want to use.

Comment: Do you have to make ONE http request to get the JSON for EACH image? that's very inefficient. Try to see if there's a way to get a JSON array with a list. Say you request from 1-20 and when you reach 20 in your list, you request from 21-40, etc. Then you parse the urls, and feed your ListView adapter with that. Picasso will simply take the image url, it doesn't really care where the URL came from. ;)